# Use Perl to check if a string has only English characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with submissions like this

```
%TRYYVJT128F93506D3<SEP>SOYKCDV12AB0185D99<SEP>Rainie Yang<SEP>Ai Wo Qing shut up (OT: Shotgun(Aka Shot Gun))
%TRYYVHU128F933CCB3<SEP>SOCCHZY12AB0185CE6<SEP>Tepr<SEP>Achète-moi
```

I am stripping everything but the song name by using this regex.

```
$line =~ s/.*>|([([\/\_\-:"``+=*].*)|(feat.*)|[?¿!¡\.;&\$@%#\\|]//g;
```

I want to make sure that the only strings printed are ones that contain only English characters, so in this case it would the first song title `Ai Wo Quing shut up` and not the next one because of the `è`.

I have tried this

```
if ( $line =~ m/[^a-zA-z0-9_]*$/ ) {
    print $line;
}
else {
    print "Non-english\n";
```

I thought this would match just the English characters, but it always prints `Non-english`. I feel this is me being rusty with regex, but I cannot find my answer.

Comment: Note your character class: `a-zA-z`. They are case sensitive, and `A-z` covers a LOT more characters than `A-Z` would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following from the comments, your problem would appear to be:

```
$line =~ m/[^a-zA-z0-9_]*$/
```

Specifically - the `^` is inside the brackets, which means that it's not acting as an 'anchor'. It's actually a negation operator

See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Negation

> It is also possible to instead list the characters you do not want to match. You can do so by using a caret (^) as the first character in the character class. For instance, [^a-z] matches any character that is not a lowercase ASCII letter, which therefore includes more than a million Unicode code points. The class is said to be "negated" or "inverted".

But the important part is - that without the 'start of line' anchor, your regular expression is zero-or-more instances (of whatever), so will match pretty much anything - because it can freely ignore the line content.

(Borodin's answer covers some of the other options for this sort of pattern match, so I shan't reproduce).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you need, so here are a couple of observations that speak to what you have written.

It is probably best if you use `split` to divide each line of data on `<SEP>`, which I presume is a *separator*. Your question asks for the fourth such field, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /<SEP>/;
    say $fields[3];
}

__DATA__
%TRYYVJT128F93506D3<SEP>SOYKCDV12AB0185D99<SEP>Rainie Yang<SEP>Ai Wo Qing shut up (OT: Shotgun(Aka Shot Gun))
%TRYYVHU128F933CCB3<SEP>SOCCHZY12AB0185CE6<SEP>Tepr<SEP>Achète-moi
```

**output**

```
Ai Wo Qing shut up (OT: Shotgun(Aka Shot Gun))
Achète-moi
```

Also, the `word` character class `\w` matches exactly `[a-zA-z0-9_]` (and `\W` matches the complement) so you can rewrite your `if` statement like this

```
if ( $line =~ /\W/ ) {
    print "Non-English\n";
}
else {
    print $line;
}
```