# Using Perl to count non-special characters in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to have Perl count only the non-special characters (as in what one can find on a US keyboard: numbers letters, `%$#()`, etc.)

```
my $stg = "é§I¥3§";
```

For the string above, I have tried several examples from threads such as these: [Use Perl to check if a string has only English characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488681/use-perl-to-check-if-a-string-has-only-english-characters)

```
my $char_count = () = $stg =~ /[[:alpha:]]/;
my $char_count = () = $stg =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9_]/;
my $char_count = () = $stg =~ /[^a-zA-z0-9_]*$/;
```

All of them give me 1 when the answer I am looking for is: 2 (only 'I' and '3' counted). Can anyone tell me what the correct solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get 1 because your regular expression stops after the 1st match.  You will get 2 if you add the [//g modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers)  ("Match globally") to your last 2 regexes:

```
my $char_count = () = $stg =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9_]/g;

my $char_count = () = $stg =~ /[^a-zA-z0-9_]*$/g;
```

The [:alpha:](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass) regex only matches `I`, not `3`.  It will return 1 even with `//g`:

```
alpha  Any alphabetical character (e.g., [A-Za-z]).
```

Answer (score 2):

Transliteration is another method for counting. With the `/c` flag, it uses the complement of the characters you specify:

```
my $non_ascii_count = $stg =~ tr/a-zA-Z0-9_//c;
```

Comment: Great answer @brian-d-foy. Thank you.